# Excel: How to update multiple tables at the same time

Tags: vba, excel

I have these 2 tables in two different sheets in excel. They both have common tabs but the only one I am concerned about is the student ID. What I would like to do is make changes to the student ID in the first table and have it reflected in the second tables student ID for data consistency. I am working in excel 2010 and everything I have researched is for later versions of excel. I have tried the special link technique but because these are 2 tables it does not work. The special link option does not appear. I am not sure if I need a script to do this or if excel 2010 has a built in way to do this.

First Table:

```
Student ID  Last name   Initial Age Program
STF348-245  Another     L.       21 Drafting
STF348-246  Different   R.       19 Science
STF348-247  Name        G.       18 Arts
STF348-248  Going       L.       23 Nursing
STF348-249  Up          M.       37 Science
STF348-250  And         J.       20 Arts
STF348-251  Down        F.       26 Business
STF348-252  Different   S.       22 Arts
STF348-253  Different   W.       20 Nursing
STF348-254  Different   L.       19 Drafting
```

Second Table:

```
Student ID  Last name   Initial Age Program
STF348-245  Another      L.      21 Drafting
STF348-246  Different    R.      19 Science
STF348-247  Name         G.      18 Arts
STF348-248  Going        L.      23 Nursing
STF348-249  Up           M.      37 Science
STF348-250  And          J.      20 Arts
STF348-251  Down         F.      26 Business
STF348-252  Different    S.      22 Arts
STF348-253  Different    W.      20 Nursing
STF348-254  Different    L.      19 Drafting
```

Comment: Clarified a little more

Comment: @Jeeped, I don't know if OP is asking for tables to be consolidated as per your suggested dupe, or if OP just wants changes in one to be reflected automatically in another. I don't think you should have been so quick to close in this instance.

Comment: @CallumDA I am looking for the second thing you said. I do not get the paste special link option when trying to copy and paste from table to table. it works for cells just fine but not for tables.

Comment: In which case it is definitely not a duplicate - I have voted to reopen this question so that you might be able to get answers

Comment: @CallumDA - The OP has shown no effort and supplied no sample data ([mcve]); the only question is '*is it possible*'. The answer is **Yes, it is possible**. If the OP decides to put in any effort then they can find the solution themselves and if they run into trouble, they can post back with specifics and I'm sure that all of the volunteers here will run to assist in any way they can. btw, I'm sorry if I caused you any grief with my comment to your response a few days ago; I have read the Q&A on meta but stayed out of the issue as it was somewhat about me.

Comment: @Jeeped, I completely agree that the question isn't clear - hence the confusion in the first place. I tend to think that unless something is definitely an exact dupe it shouldn't be marked as such. -- about the post the other day, no problem at all. I went to Meta to get clarification, and I got a lot more than I expected haha. You were right to comment as you did, and they backed that up so it's good enough for me :)

Comment: Added pictures for clarification.

Comment: Pictures are not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For starters, you're asking everyone who might otherwise help you, to manually recreate your table structure (instead, you could provide plain text examples in your question, which makes copy/paste more easy to do).

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? "I am just not sure how to accomplish this" -- How do you *think* you might accomplish this? Have you researched similar topics and attempted to implement those solutions? Show your work...

Comment: You might also consider elaborating on what the results should be, and why. It may not be apparent what field(s) have changed and/or whether any other field(s) change as a result, etc.

Comment: With the exception of inserting new rows, this can be accomplished using the `VLOOKUP` function only, assuming the student ID field is a unique identifier. E.g., in the "Program" field, put: `=VLOOKUP([@[Student ID]],Table1,5,False))` and drag the formula down. Now any changes to Program on Table1 will be reflected in Table2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the exception of inserting or appending new rows, this can be accomplished using the `VLOOKUP` function only, assuming the Student ID field is a unique identifier.

In the "Program" field of Table2, put:

```
=VLOOKUP([@[Student ID]],Table1,5,False))
```

Copy/Drag the formula down. Now any changes to Program on Table1 will be reflected in Table2.

Follow the same procedure for other columns, simply using the appropriate header name as the first argument to the function, and making sure to also change the column Index (`5` in the above example).

**NB:** This assumes the "first" table is named "Table1" -- if not, modify the formula accordingly.

If you want to preserve the tables as strict duplicates of one another, including *order*, then you don't even need `VLOOKUP`. In Table2, just do:

```
Student ID             | Student Name             | Last Name
=Table1[@[Student ID]] | =Table1[@[Student Name]] | =Table1[@[Last Name]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this perfectly answers my question.

Comment: Quick question for you. When I place that formula is the program field am i replacing the values that are already there? Such as Drafting, Science, etc..

Comment: Yes, of course. You need to overwrite the existing *value* with the formula that will *dynamically* return the results from the other table.

Comment: Okay if that's the case, it says there is an error in the formula. not 100% sure where it might be because it does not give me specifics